# Can't get rid of Site Template in SP 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We are currently in the process of upgrading to SharePoint 2013. We have gotten all the way to importing the content databases. While using the Test-SPContentDatabase we found a "MissingSiteDefinition".  It does not give a name but a four digit ID number. We used

```
Get-SPWebTemplate | select Name, ID
```

and found the four digit ID number to be tied to a template. We have deleted the site containing the template and are trying to remove the template since it is on a site that is no longer in use and is a specialty template that is not compatible with 2013. 
When we run

```
Uninstall-SPWebTemplate -identity [Name of template]
```

it does not throw an error. However, when I again run

```
Get-SPWebTemplate | select Name, ID
```

it is still listed. The site that referenced this template has been deleted and we have to run

```
Remove-SPDeletedSite
```

to fully remove the site. However, the template remains. I am sure we are missing a simple step.

Answer (score 0):

Was the template applied to the site via a SharePoint Solution/Feature? I have seen this a few times where SharePoint will not remove a artifact until the source feature is removed.